# PropertyNotWritableException when doing fn:length

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, el

I've got `javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException` when trying to store the lenght of the table in hidden input for **JavaScript**:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /view/ci/buttons.xhtml at line 34 and column 73 value="#{fn:length(order.phases)}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:125)
```

The JSF:

```
<h:inputHidden id="phasesCount" value="#{fn:length(order.phases)}"/>
```

I don't understand that error, fn:length is supported to be read only operation, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Just bind the `<h:inputHidden` value to a property in your managed bean, and set it's value using JavaScript before sending the data to the server.

Comment: If you want to use it for JavaScript only, move the `<h:inputHidden>` outside from any `<h:form>` in that way it won't be sended to the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is fully expected. The `<h:inputHidden>` is also processed on form submit. This allows among others manipulation of the hidden value by JavaScript. However, an EL function call is not a valid setter method operation. Hence this exception. Like as with every other [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) component, the value has to be a fullworthy bean property.

Given your concrete functional requirement of passing a variable to JavaScript, the `<h:inputHidden>` is actually the wrong tool for the job. Just let JSF print it as if it's a JS variable instead:

```html
<script>var phasesCount = #{fn:length(order.phases)};</script>
```

Or, if you *really* need a hidden input element even though it has no utter use in the server side, then use a plain HTML element instead:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="phasesCount" value="#{fn:length(order.phases)}" />
```

Note that you could as good use a completely arbitrary HTML element or attribute for the same job:

```html
<div id="phasesCount" data-phasesCount="#{fn:length(order.phases)}">
```

This value is also accessible by JS means.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've made quick workaround with script (without full controll when it will be refreshed and launched with partial submit&refresh) but I've forgotten to simply try with 'normal' html inputs :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can use `<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">` or `<o:onloadScript>` to automatically re-execute a script on every ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:inputHidden id="phasesCount" value="#{fn:length(order.phases)}"/>
```

`inputHidden` is an [input control](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html). JSF will try to call [setValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#setValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object%29) on this expression when the form is submitted.

Comment: ?? this is exactly the code I have posted and is not functioning

Comment: @McDowell means JSF is trying to write your property when he finds a binding to a managed bean property, but it's a function.

Comment: @lechlukasz I have not posted a solution, I have explained why you are getting an error - you can only use an editable property binding in an input control.

Comment: But writing to function makes no sense. It is JSF error than? If so, how to work around?

Comment: JSF tries to write if he finds a property, but apparently you can use constant values like '123' on it. So it can be a fixed predefined value. http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_inputHidden.html

Comment: @lechlukasz 1) I believe it is possible for a function to resolve to a bean with a property, so functions are not automatically prohibited. 2) EL is evaluated at runtime, so it doesn't fail until you try to use it. I expect the piece of code that fails lacks the context to give you a more meaningful message.